# Почему при переходе на новую строку в display: flex контейнер растягивается по максимум?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день!

```
 <div class="container">
                        <div class="item"></div>
                        <div class="item"></div>
                        <div class="item"></div>
                        <div class="item"></div>
                        <div class="item"></div>
                        <div class="item"></div>
                        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <style>
                .container{
                    display:inline-flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    max-width: 700px;

                    border: .2px solid black;
                }

                .item{
                    width: 150px;
                    height: 50px;
                    border: .2px solid red;
                    margin: 4px;
                }
    </style>`
```

Почему при переходе элемента на новую строку, контейнер растягивается по максимуму а не содержимому? и как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну если написать что align-items:flex-start то это свойство не не будет stretch и тогда будет как задумано а  на скрине типичное поведение stretch

Answer (score 0):

Контейнер по умолчанию наследует ширину родителя. В Вашем случае вплоть до 700px. Если хотите сделать визуально симпатичнее, используйте выравнивание элементов, например: justify-content: space-between;

Comment: другое решение возможно, пусть даже не flex? необходимы конкретные отступы между элементами, поэтому это свойство не могу принимать.

Comment: вполне возможно. Сделайте justify-content: center; и будут Вам фиксированные отступы между элементами.